# Why doesn't the cout command print a message?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cout

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int x = 42;
cout << x; // This line doesn't print! Why?
    return 0;
}
```

Screenshot of Visual C++: http://bildr.no/image/ZlVBV0k0.jpeg

This code gives me nothing but a black console window that flashes by when I click on debug. Isn't the number 42 supposed to be printed in the console window? This is my first application in C++. I have experience in C# from high school.

EDIT:

Now I have tried this code:

```
// Primtallsgenerator.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int x = 42;
cout << x << endl; // This line doesn't print! Why?
cin >> x;
    return 0;
}
```

It still doesn't work. Screenshot of the code here: http://bildr.no/image/ODNRc3lG.jpeg

The black windows still just flashes by...

Comment: and with `cout << x << flush;` or `cout << x << endl;` ?

Comment: @ThePluc That shouldn't be necessary. The destructors call `flush()`.

Comment: Right click your project -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem -> Console

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yeah, the flush was useless. I assume it's a console issue, I thought the newline could help. This definitly works on a linux terminal but might be hard to read ^^

Comment: Run the program outside of the debugger (Ctrl-F5).  In that mode the console window will prompt you to close it. I'm not sure why it doesn't do so when the debugger is used - I guess they figure you can get similar behavior in the debugger by setting a breakpoint on the return from `main()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to note:

First, you are not forcing the buffer to flush, so there is no guarantee the output is being sent to the screen before the program ends.  Change your `cout` statement to:

```
cout << x << endl;
```

Second, Visual Studio will close the console when it ends (in Debugging mode).  If you do not debug it (Ctrl-F5 by default), it will keep the console open until you press a key.  This will allow you to see the output.  Alternatively, you can add a `cin.get()` before your return statement which will force the program to wait for a character to be in the input stream before the program is allowed to exit.

Answer (score 2):

It did print the message, it was just too fast for you to see.

add this command:

```
cin >> x;
```

or this one

```
while(true) {}
```

before the return statement.

Comment: That last one's an infinite loop. How about just `std::cin.get()`.

Comment: How about this one:  `cin.ignore(100000, '\n');`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will print the number. Then the program ends, and the console window is closed. Run it in the debugger, and put a breakpoint on the `return 0;` line. Then you'll see it.

Comment: I've tried that know. You can see the screenshot in my edited OP. The black console window still just flashes by, even with the breakpoint.

Answer (score 2):

This code should work fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    cout << x; 

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Also check this documentation about [getchar()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/).

Comment: It still just flashes by! I feel like an idiot now, but no code samples from any of my books work neither. Something is wrong >:[

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with a console application in Visual Studio, you have to go to your project's linker properties and set your `SubSystem` setting to `CONSOLE`.

And get a habit of running your code *without a debugger* (Ctrl+F5 by default) when you don't need the debugger. That way the console window will not flash and disappear by itself.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use system pause at the end before the "return 0" statement like this:

```
system("PAUSE");
```

This is cleaner and much more effective.